# DLM with autocorrelated and non gaussian residuals

Tags: state-space-models, dlm

I quite new to state-space modelling, and I've been working on a DLM right now, using the **dlm** package (Petris, 2009). I want to forecast French car registrations since 1994 (till  2014), on a monthly basis. The serie is seasonally adjusted. I used the command line dlmModPoly with an order of 2.
The residuals seem not gaussian (after processing a Shapiro-Wilk test), and autocorrelated (Ljung-Box test). Do you any kind of transformation that could overcome theses limitations?

ps; I can share the code I used, if needed.

Comment: Have you tried adding AR components to your model?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I added AR components, and the model works well.